# getting users with join using concat

Tags: mysql

but why when I select I get each result `repeated 4 times`
I want to select all users from table users. but am joining table items coz I want to check some info

```
TABLE USERS

USERID   FNAME   LNAME  EMAIL
1        JANE    DEO    TES@TES.COM
2        JEO     DEO    TES@TES.COM


TABLE ITEMS 

PRODCUT_ID  PRODUCT  PRICE 
1           RICE     400
2           MENGO    100


SELECT SND.USERID, SND.FNAME, SND.LNAME
FROM users AS SND
INNER JOIN items AS M
WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'), '%', '%')
```

Comment: which information you need to check from itemtables?

Comment: You are not joining `ON` a specific column, it sounds unusual.

Comment: Looks like insufficient data. On which columns you want to Join USERS and ITEMS  ?

Comment: @Gufran and @vahdet am trying to do this `SELECT SND.USERID, SND.FNAME, SND.LNAME FROM users AS SND INNER JOIN items AS M WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'), '%', '%') AND NOT (
       M.PRODCUT_ID = '1'
   AND M.PRICE = '400'
   AND M.PRODUCT = 'RICE'
  )`  so i want to get the rest users apart from jane

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify join rule in `ON` clause, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS SND
INNER JOIN items AS M ON SND.USERID = M.USERID
```

otherwise you have cartesian product, like in your case.

**BUT:** In your schema you don't have field `USERID` in your table `items` so you have to determine join rule.

Comment: i had similar example like this. your example only brings users which are in tble items. not users in tble users. i want to get all users in tble users not items. i only want items tble to check some users if they there or not

Comment: @JoseLee In this case use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM users AS SND
LEFT JOIN items AS M ON SND.USERID` it works  that way. coz when i add on `SND.USERID = M.USERID` i get nothing. so still facing some problem i get results repeated. like JOE JOE JOE JEO 4 times

Comment: fixed my problem by using DISTINCT

Comment: @JoseLee Have you seen `explain` for your query? Are you happy with performance, speed?